# How to Validate OpenID Connect Access Token generated by identityserver4 in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

How to Validate OpenID Connect Access Token generated by identityserver4 in ASP.NET WEB API.

The Scenario is

1. I have one Angular Client Application which is getting one OpenID Connect Access Token after Login.
2. Now That Client Application wants some information from one ASP.NET API. 
   Client can call the API along with the Access Token.

**But Question is, How should I validate that Token in my ASP.NET API???**

I can easily do that in **ASP.NET CORE API**.

**BUT I NEED Solution to do the same in ASP.NET API.** (Not in core)
Thanks in advance.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
                {
                    o.ApiName = "APINameRegisteredInIdentityServer";
                    o.ApiSecret = "SomeAPISecreteValue";
                    o.Authority = "MyAuthorityURL";
                    o.SaveToken = true;
                    o.SupportedTokens = IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.SupportedTokens.Both;
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` OWIN middleware package, even for Identity Server 4 tokens - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.

There are samples here - https://github.com/IdentityServer/CrossVersionIntegrationTests

Comment: Hi devdigital, I already mentioned in my question is, I can do this in ASP.NET CORE. I need solution for ASP.NET Framework API template.

Comment: This is for OWIN based .NET 4.x projects, not .NET Core

Comment: If you’re not OWIN based, it would be easier to convert to OWIN

Comment: Hi devdigital, Can you please provide me the sample how to validate the access token in API... or How to Protect API using OPEN ID CONNECT?
or
Is anyone help me how to use this Nuget? 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/

Comment: Hi All - Please help me, I was literally stuck here from last 5 days... Need help... Thanks in advance

Comment: I am getting this access token from my Angular Client Application issued by IDP.



{
  "nbf": 1529176096,<br/>
  "exp": 1529179696,<br/>
  "iss": "https://localhost:44381",
  "aud": [
    "https://localhost:44381/resources",
    "mywebapicore"
  ],
  "client_id": "AngularCore",
  "sub": "1",
  "auth_time": 1529175083,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "mywebapicore"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}

Comment: WEB API CODE 



app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {

                    ClientId = "AngularCore",
                    Authority = "https://localhost:44381/",
                    TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "mywebapicore"
                    }
                });

Comment: Have a look at the KatanaApiIdSrv4... samples in the sample link in my answer.

Comment: Hi @Devdigital - Yes this Example is working but the Actual token which I am getting in my Real Application, for that Its not working... In My Real application, I am getting one Access Token, which is not getting validated using IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions

Comment: Can you please take a look at it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891611/implement-openid-connect-authetication-in-asp-net-web-api