# Implement OpenID connect Authetication in asp.net WEB API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, owin-middleware

[This is the Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh2JF.jpg)

This is the **access_token** I am getting in My Angular Client Application.

```js
{
  "nbf": 1529181048,
  "exp": 1529184648,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44381",
  "aud": [
    "https://localhost:44381/resources",
    "myaspnetwebapi"
  ],
  "client_id": "AngularCore",
  "sub": "1",
  "auth_time": 1529181045,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "myaspnetwebapi"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

In My ASP.NET WEB API Project, 
I am using this OPEN ID CONNECT Nuget Package - 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/

I have written the following code to validate the Token **But I am getting 401.**
Please please help me. I am stuck like anything. :( 
Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());


            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {

                    ClientId = "AngularCore",
                    Authority = "https://localhost:44381",
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "myaspnetwebapi"
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note this component is designed for user interactive clients, not WebApi's. Have you looked at using bearer tokens instead?

Comment: @Tratcher - I have tried bearer  as well but no luck... :(

Comment: Does anyone knows how can we solve this issue????????

Comment: what error are you getting? set IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII=true, so we can see the full error.